# platform with multilple paypal vendors

Tags: paypal

I'm building an Elance style site for a client who wants paypal incorporated so job posters can pay the job winners.

Would each job winner need to go to Paypal, get the unique Paypal HTML which creates the "Pay with Paypal" button for them, and then input this on our platform? Or is there  another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways this could be done.

You could generate buttons for people using the [Button Manager API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ButtonMgrAPIIntro).

You could also use [Express Checkout](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-and-integration-guides#ec) along with the [Permissions API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_PermissionsAbout) so you can have a single checkout system that works with everybody involved.

You could use [Adaptive Payments](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro) in a number of different ways depending on your needs.

Really going to need more details about what your overall goal is to provide a better recommendation, but yes, those would be better options than having job winners create their own buttons.

Comment: Thank you. Since I've learned the platform takes a percentage too, I've decided to use the chained payments component of adaptive payments. Is that a good option?